# android : app crash if user inputs two decimal points like "1..5" instead of "1.5"

Tags: android, decimal

i have an android program where i have successfully restricted the user to input only value after decimal.. the problem is if user inputs two decimal points like "1.." then the app crashes. i have allowed only one special character to be used i.e decimal point itself. so how can i restrict the user from entering two decimal points or else show some validation.

i need something like this

```
  else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().equals(".."))
             {


                txtLdays.requestFocus();    
                txtLdays.setError("Double decimal ?");  

                 return false;
             }
```

Comment: `myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));`

Comment: Set the input type of edittext to numberDecimal android:inputType="numberDecimal

Comment: A more robust way would be to use a regular expression matcher. Please see my full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Use `contains` like below

```
else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().contains(".."))
         {


            txtLdays.requestFocus();    
            txtLdays.setError("Double decimal ?");  

             return false;
         }
```

**EDIT**

**String** to **double**

```
double result = Double.parseDouble(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim());
```

**int** to **double**

```
double result = (double) 12;
```

If user enters **12.**

then check `endsWith`

```
double result;
if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().endsWith("."))
   result = Double.parseDouble(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().replace("\\.", ""))
```

Comment: IS there any universal way that whenever the app crashes. instead of crashing it shows some error and asks user to try again properly?

Comment: @tusharnarang Use Try catch method. if error happen catch will get that error. that time give toast. tell the user do it again.

Comment: thanks will do that... good answer .. but what if user inputs only one decimal and forgets to input 0 after decimal.. any way to add zeo after decimal if no value is inputted

Comment: @tusharnarang use `double result = (double) 12;` that will return **12.0**

Comment: where should i use this line sir ? bcoz the it is not always 12

Comment: i have simple edit text which inputs only numeric value and decimal point where user is retricted to one decimal place

Comment: @tusharnarang sorry that mean 12 is `txtLdays.getText().toString().trim()` value getting from `EditText`

Comment: It says cannot cast from  string to double

Comment: public void singleDecimal()
   {
    double result = Double.parseDouble(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim());
    txtLdays.setText(result);
   
   }

Comment: @tusharnarang no that will convert 12 to 12.0

Comment: ok. what about 12. if user inputs nothing after decimal how do i check it?

Comment: else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().endsWith("."))
          {
          
              
          txtLdays.requestFocus();
             txtLdays.setError("Enter Value after Decimal");

Comment: this works fine with my validation but is there a way to add zero automatically after (12.) in the validation itself. via calling some function

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilitites

1. if you want to restrict when any button pressed..
   then replace all `".."` characters with empty chars like..

   `String data=View.getText().toString().replaceAll("..", "")`;

2.if you restrict when the user is typing then write a `TextWatcher` listener for the `Edittext` and you need to peform some validations there...

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried setting decimal input type ?

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"    
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
int count = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf((txtLdays, ".");

if (count > 1){

    txtLdays.requestFocus();    
    txtLdays.setError("Double decimal ?");  


}
```

Please downlaod this jar file [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

Comment: IS there any universal way that whenever the app crashes. instead of crashing it shows some error and asks user to try again properly?

Comment: Put your code within try catch and show error message in catch or final block, but remember its not a good habit, if you already aware with exception then put some logical code for handling that type of situation,

Comment: yes i did that but do i want if any app crash error occurs . there should be an alert kind of something

Comment: You can use `UncaughtExceptions` in your Application for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The right way would be to match the value against a regular expression.

Here is an example that allows a string that starts/end with zero or more spaces and contains a double decimal point number:

```
//First make sure you avoid null pointer exception
if (txtLdays != null && txtLdays.getText() != null) {
    String daysString = txtLdays.getText().toString();
    String regex = "^\s*\d+\.\.\d+\s*$"

    if (daysString.matches(regex)) {
        txtLdays.requestFocus();    
        txtLdays.setError("Double decimal ?");  

        return false;
    }
}
```

You can youse some kind of [online regular expression tool](http://regexpal.com/) to verify your matcher.

Answer (score 0):

equals will check Object.
You need to check `equalsIngnoreCase();` this ll check all the character
specially u need

```
else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().indexOf("..") != -1 ){
             txtLdays.requestFocus();    
             txtLdays.setError("Double decimal ?");  
             return false;
}
```

Comment: IS there any universal way that whenever the app crashes. instead of crashing it shows some error and asks user to try again properly?

Comment: @tusharnarang You can handle crashes by Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in android. But this ll occur any error in app.you need to handle your exception properly then only you come to know where it caused.For your case handle exception in getting value from EditText.

Comment: yes but i do not need it just for editText i want it if any app crash occurs then a toast or alert box should occur

Comment: Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
   @Override
   public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
  });

Comment: where do i use this insisde a function ?

Comment: @tusharnarang For more reference http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/04/global-exception-handling-and-sending.html